# Call Ajax.ActionLink using Razor syntax on value changed event

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View in which i have criteria a Supplier TextBox a LastMonth dropdown and a Months Textbox.

```
 @using JouleBrokerDB.ViewModels;
    @model AssignPayReportToDepositViewModel
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "View";
    }
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      .treediv {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 440px;
        /*height:400px;*/
        min-height: 400px;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0 2em;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #8AC007;
        padding: 15px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Show", "AssignPayReportToDeposit", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AssignToPayReportForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
          <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Assign Pay Report to Deposit</legend>

            <div class="form-group">

              <!-- Supplier -->
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label("", "Supplier:", new { @class = "control-label", @for = "textinput" })
                <div id="suppliers">
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SuppliersList, new SelectList(Model.SuppliersList, "SupplierID", "Name"), new { id = "ddSupplier", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Last Month -->
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label("", "Last Month:", new { @class = "control-label", @for = "textinput" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LastMonthsList, new SelectList(Model.LastMonthsList), new { @id = "ddLastMonth", @class = "form-control" })
              </div>

              <!-- Months-->
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label("", "Months:", new { @class = "control-label", @for = "textinput" })
                @Html.TextBox("txtMonths", null, new { type = "number", step = 1, min = 1, max = 12, @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>

          <div class="treediv">
            @Html.Label("", "UnAssigned PayReport:", new { @class = "control-label", @for = "textinput" })
            <div id="TreeView_UPR" style="padding:5px"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="treediv">
            @Html.Label("", "Deposits:", new { @class = "control-label", @for = "textinput" })
            <h4></h4>
            <div id="TreeView_AD" style="padding:5px"></div>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Views/AssignPayReportToDeposit/Show.js")"></script>
```

Here on this text box i have attached changed event though jQuery. The requirement is that whenever the criteria changes the treeview div will be filled with data will be refreshed.

```
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AttachEvents = function () {
  $("#ddSupplier").change(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnSupplierChange);
  $("#ddLastMonth").change(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnLastMonthChange);
  $("#txtMonths").change(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnMonthsChange);
}
```

these changed event handler will handle the refreshing the treeview. The whole thing is handled through ajax calls.

Now i know that using Ajax.ActionLink and UpdateTargetId parameter with Replace option i can return the treeview in partial view so the manual handling can be removed. but that will require me put the anchor button which user have to click. Requirement is that the refresh of treeview should be done on any criteria change.

Is there any way i am able to achieve this using Ajax.ActionLink (or any another razor syntax that will take load off from the manual handling ) ? On change event of the controls i would like to call a controller using ajax.actionlink which will return a partialview and update the div.

Edit: I am handling this through jQuery right now. so i will post the complete code for more understanding.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using JouleBrokerDB;
using JouleBrokerDB.ViewModels;
using JouleBroker.Filters;

namespace JouleBroker.Controllers
{
  [RoutePrefix("AssignPayReportToDeposit")]
  [Route("{action=Show}")]
  public class AssignPayReportToDepositController : Controller
  {
    // GET: AssignPayReportToDeposit
    //[Route("Show",Name = "APTDShow")]
    //[ValidateLogin]
    public ActionResult Show()
    {
      List<SupplierViewModel> suppliers = DBCommon.GetAllSuppliers(false);

      SuppliersList_LastMonthsList_ViewModel model = new SuppliersList_LastMonthsList_ViewModel()
      {
        SuppliersList = suppliers,
        LastMonthsList = new List<string>()
      };

      return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetUnAssignedPayReports")]
    public JsonResult GetUnAssignedPayReports(int SupplierID,
                                              string MonthPaid,
                                              int Months)
    {
      var payreports = AssignPayReportsToDepositData.GetUnAssignedPayReports(SupplierID,
                                                                             MonthPaid,
                                                                             Months);
      return Json(payreports);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetAssignedPayReports")]
    public JsonResult GetAssignedPayReports(int SupplierID,
                                            string MonthPaid,
                                            int Months)
    {
      var payreports = AssignPayReportsToDepositData.GetAssignedPayReports(SupplierID,
                                                                           MonthPaid,
                                                                           Months);
      return Json(payreports);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AssignDepositIdToPayReport")]
    public bool AssignDepositIdToPayReport(int PayReportID, int DepositID)
    {
      return AssignPayReportsToDepositData.AssignDepositIdToPayReport(PayReportID, DepositID);
    }
  }
}
```

JavaScript File (the code is a bit lengthy so you don't need to look at all of them you can see the methods which are calling the action methods. GetUnAssignedPayReports and GetAssignedPayReports which returns the data which is used to fill the tree view.) I just want this portion to moved to partial view and passing model to partial view generate treeview there and replace the div each time on change event with rendering partial view again. Hope i am clear enough. so change the above methods to return partial instead of json result that what i am trying to achive

```
function AssignPayReportsToDeposit() { }

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID = 0;
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth = null;
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedMonths = 0;

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastMonthsList = null;
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.UnAssignedPayReportsList = null;
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignedPayReportsList = null;

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode = null;
//--------- Document Ready Function -------- //
$(document).ready(function () {

  //AttachEvents
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AttachEvents();
});

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AttachEvents = function () {
  $("#ddSupplier").change(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnSupplierChange);
  $("#ddLastMonth").change(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnLastMonthChange);
  $("#txtMonths").change(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnMonthsChange);
}

//Handles Supplier ChangeEvents
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnSupplierChange = function () {
  //Get Changed Supplier ID
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID = $('#ddSupplier').val();
  //Get Last Month List
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastMonthsList = CommonAction.GetLastPayReportMonthsBySupplierID(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID);
  //Fill Last Month List
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.FillLastMonths();
  //Refresh TreeView_UPR
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewUPR();
  //Refresh TreeView_AD
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewAD();
}

//Handles Last Month Change Event
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnLastMonthChange = function () {
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth = $('#ddLastMonth').val();
  //Refresh TreeView_UPR
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewUPR();
  //Refresh TreeView_AD
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewAD();
}

//Handles Month Change Event
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnMonthsChange = function () {
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedMonths = $('#txtMonths').val();
  //Refresh TreeView_UPR
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewUPR();
  //Refresh TreeView_AD
  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewAD();
}

//Fills Last Month Dropdown with options
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.FillLastMonths = function () {
  var ddLastMonth = $("#ddLastMonth");
  if (ddLastMonth != undefined) {
    ddLastMonth.empty();
    if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastMonthsList != undefined) {
      $.each(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastMonthsList, function () {
        Common.AddOptionToSelect(ddLastMonth, this.Text, this.Text);
      });
      ddLastMonth.val(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastMonthsList[0].Text);
      AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth = ddLastMonth.val();
    }
  }
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.ValidateControls = function () {
  var success = true;
  if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID == undefined ||
      AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID == 0) {
    //  bootbox.alert('Please select a Supplier');
    success = false;
  }
  else if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth == undefined ||
          AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth == '') {
    //   bootbox.alert('Please select Last Month');
    success = false;
  }
  else if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedMonths == undefined ||
          AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedMonths == 0) {
    //  bootbox.alert('Please Enter Months');
    success = false;
  }
  return success;
}

//Assigns DepositIdToPayReport
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignDepositIdToPayReport = function (PayReportID, DepositID) {
  var success = false;
  if (PayReportID != undefined && DepositID != undefined) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ PayReportID: PayReportID, DepositID: DepositID });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'AssignPayReportToDeposit/AssignDepositIdToPayReport',
      data: jsonData,
      async: false,
      success: function (result) {
        success = result;
      },
      error: Common.AjaxErrorHandler
    });
  }
  return success;
}

//--------- Tree View  UPR Functions -------- //
//Gets UnAssigned Pay Reports
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.GetUnAssignedPayReports = function () {
  var payReports;
  if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.ValidateControls()) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(
      {
        SupplierID: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID,
        MonthPaid: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth,
        Months: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedMonths
      });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "AssignPayReportToDeposit/GetUnAssignedPayReports",
      data: jsonData,
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
        if (data != undefined && data != "")
          payReports = data;
      },
      error: Common.AjaxErrorHandler
    });
  }
  return payReports;
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.BindTreeViewUPR = function () {
    var treeview = $("#TreeView_UPR");

    var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
      data: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.UnAssignedPayReportsList,
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "PayReportID"
        }
      }
    });

    treeview.kendoTreeView({
      dragAndDrop: true,
      dataSource: inline,
      dataBound: function (e) {
        if (!this.dataSource.data().length) {
          this.element.append("<p class='no-items'>No items yet.</p>");
        } else {
          this.element.find(".no-items").remove();
        }
      },
      dataTextField: ["DisplayValue"],
      drop: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnTreeViewUPRDrop
    });
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnTreeViewUPRDrop = function (e) {
  var isTargetTreeViewAD = false;
  var sourceDataItem = this.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
  var targetDataItem = this.dataItem(e.destinationNode);
  if (targetDataItem == undefined) {
    targetDataItem = $("#TreeView_AD").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(e.destinationNode);
    isTargetTreeViewAD = true;
  }

  if (sourceDataItem == undefined ||
      targetDataItem == undefined) {
    //Source and target both must exists
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (sourceDataItem.IsDeposit == true) {
    //Deposits cannot be drag and Drop
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (isTargetTreeViewAD) {
    if (e.dropPosition == "over" &&
        sourceDataItem.IsPayReport == true &&
        sourceDataItem.IsAssignedPayReport == false &&
        targetDataItem.IsDeposit == true) {
      //Source must UnAssigned Payreport Target Must be Deposit and Drop position must over 
      //Implement logic to assign deposit id to the Pay Report
      var PayReportID = sourceDataItem.PayReportID;
      var DepositID = targetDataItem.DepositID;
      if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignDepositIdToPayReport(PayReportID, DepositID)) {
        sourceDataItem.set("DepositID", DepositID);
        sourceDataItem.set("IsAssignedPayReport", true);
      }
      else {
        //Didnt update the record don't do the drop
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    }
    else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    if ((e.dropPosition == "before" || e.dropPosition == "after") &&
          sourceDataItem.IsPayReport == true &&
          targetDataItem.IsPayReport == true &&
          targetDataItem.IsAssignedPayReport == false) {
      //Only allow sorting in this condition otherwise cancel drop event
      //Means only allow sorting of unassigned payreports within the tree
    }
    else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewUPR = function () {
  //Destroy and empty tree
  var treeview = $("#TreeView_UPR").data("kendoTreeView");
  if (treeview != undefined) { treeview.destroy(); }
  treeview = $("#TreeView_UPR");
  treeview.empty();

  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.UnAssignedPayReportsList = AssignPayReportsToDeposit.GetUnAssignedPayReports();

  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.BindTreeViewUPR();
}

//--------- TreeView_AD Functions -------- //
//Gets Assigned Pay Reports
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.GetAssignedPayReports = function () {
  var payReports;
  if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.ValidateControls()) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(
      {
        SupplierID: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedSupplierID,
        MonthPaid: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedLastMonth,
        Months: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.SelectedMonths
      });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "AssignPayReportToDeposit/GetAssignedPayReports",
      data: jsonData,
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
        if (data != undefined && data != "")
          payReports = data;
      },
      error: Common.AjaxErrorHandler
    });
  }
  return payReports;
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.BindTreeViewAD = function () {
    var treeview = $("#TreeView_AD");

    var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
      data: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignedPayReportsList,
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "DepositID",
          hasChildren: "HasAnyAssignedPayReports",
          children: "AssignedPayReports"
        }
      }
    });

    treeview.kendoTreeView({
      dragAndDrop: true,
      dataSource: inline,
      dataBound: function (e) {
        if (!this.dataSource.data().length) {
          this.element.append("<p class='no-items'>No items yet.</p>");
        } else {
          this.element.find(".no-items").remove();
        }
      },
      dataTextField: ["DisplayValue", "DisplayValue"],
      drop: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnTreeViewADDrop,
      select: AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnTreeViewADSelect
    });
}
AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnTreeViewADSelect = function (e) {
  var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);
  var treeview = this;

  if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode != undefined) {
    //Restore last node's Text
    var previousDataItem = this.dataItem(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode);
    if (previousDataItem != undefined) {
      var date = AssignPayReportsToDeposit.FormatDepositMonthToDisplay(previousDataItem.DepositDate);
      var displaytext = "[" + date + "]" + "-[" + previousDataItem.BankName + "]-" + "[" + previousDataItem.Amount + "]";
      this.text(AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode, displaytext);
    }
    AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode = undefined;
  }
  if (dataItem.IsDeposit) {
    if (dataItem.hasChildren > 0) {
      dataItem.set("expanded", true);
      //Append  sum to selected node's diplay value
      var childs = dataItem.children.data();
      var sum = 0;
      $.each(childs, function () { sum += this.Amount });
      var date = AssignPayReportsToDeposit.FormatDepositMonthToDisplay(dataItem.DepositDate);
      var displaytext = "[" + date + "]" + "-[" + dataItem.BankName + "]-" + "[" + dataItem.Amount + "(" + sum + ")" + "]";
      this.text(e.node, displaytext)
      AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode = e.node;
    }
  }
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.FormatDepositMonthToDisplay = function (jsondate) {
  var depositedate = "";
  if (jsondate != undefined && jsondate != "") {
    var date = Common.ParseDate(jsondate);
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    depositedate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (month);
  }
  return depositedate;
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.OnTreeViewADDrop = function (e) {
  var isTargetTreeViewURP = false;
  var DroptoNoItemZone = false;
  var sourceDataItem = this.dataItem(e.sourceNode);
  var targetDataItem = this.dataItem(e.destinationNode);
  var treeview_UPR = $("#TreeView_UPR").data("kendoTreeView");
  if (targetDataItem == undefined) {
    targetDataItem = treeview_UPR.dataItem(e.destinationNode);
    if (treeview_UPR.element.find(".no-items").length > 0) DroptoNoItemZone = true;
    isTargetTreeViewURP = true;
  }

  if ((sourceDataItem == undefined ||
       targetDataItem == undefined) && DroptoNoItemZone == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (sourceDataItem.IsDeposit == true) {
    //Deposits can not be moved within the tree view
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (isTargetTreeViewURP) {
    if (((e.dropPosition == "before" || e.dropPosition == "after") &&
          sourceDataItem.IsPayReport == true &&
          sourceDataItem.IsAssignedPayReport == true &&
          targetDataItem.IsPayReport == true) || (e.dropPosition == "over" && DroptoNoItemZone)) {
      //Implement logic to unassing deposit id to PayReport
      var PayReportID = sourceDataItem.PayReportID;
      var DepositID = 0;
      if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignDepositIdToPayReport(PayReportID, DepositID)) {
        sourceDataItem.set("DepositID", DepositID);
        sourceDataItem.set("IsAssignedPayReport", false);
      }
      else {
        //Didnt update the record don't do the drop
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    }
    else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (e.dropPosition == "over" &&
        sourceDataItem.IsPayReport == true &&
        targetDataItem.IsDeposit == true) {
      //Implement Logic to change deposit ID for assigned payreport
      var PayReportID = sourceDataItem.PayReportID;
      var DepositID = targetDataItem.DepositID;
      if (AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignDepositIdToPayReport(PayReportID, DepositID)) {
        sourceDataItem.set("DepositID", DepositID);
        sourceDataItem.set("IsAssignedPayReport", true);
      }
      else {
        //Didnt update the record don't do the drop
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    }
    else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }
}

AssignPayReportsToDeposit.RefreshTreeViewAD = function () {
  //Destroy and empty tree
  var treeview = $("#TreeView_AD").data("kendoTreeView");
  if (treeview != undefined) { treeview.destroy(); }
  treeview = $("#TreeView_AD");
  treeview.empty();

  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.LastTextChangedNode = undefined;

  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.AssignedPayReportsList = AssignPayReportsToDeposit.GetAssignedPayReports();

  AssignPayReportsToDeposit.BindTreeViewAD();
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to? The Ajax helpers are just unnecessary extra overhead. What do you mean _"take  load off from the manual handling"_? And if your using the `jquery.load()` it will be less code anyway.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am using $.ajax to handle it but see my comment below for what i want to do. if i could create partial view then i would be able use partialresult and use it with flexibility that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not out the box.

The `Ajax` extension methods are really just `HTML` helpers that work with other jQuery libraries. The helpers create the relavant `HTML` markup (such as adding custom addtributes `data-*=""`) and the client scripts use this to determine their behaviour.

You could create your own `MVC` `HTML` helper and script library to handle change events for you however I would recommend looking at a front end framework such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) instead. This library would handle all the events declaratively so you don't need to waste time writing event handlers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i suppose you are right and i could use Angular. but for now i have decided to not to use it. i wanted to know if it was at all possible using just MVC and it is possible by extension methods like you said. (i asked this question because my treeview and everything is generated in javascript and right now it is for this one view only if i could achieve this somehow through partialview and razor syntax i would be able to save some coding and not repeat same things again. well it seems like creating ajax extensions for just this would be more work than i planned.)

Comment: if you can point me to any sample regarding any htmlhelper method which lets me call ajax.actionmethod on changed event that would be much appreciated. i at least would like to learn how that would work.

Comment: @KrunalParekh, A html helper method will not do this. They are for generating html on the server side before its sent to the view. In order to handle client side events, you need javascript/jquery (which is what the `Ajax` helpers do. Its a bit unclear exactly what your hoping to achieve.

Comment: If you were to create a helper method you would need client side script to support it. You could create a helper for instance that would add data-onchange="CallMethod()" to your elements. You would then need a script to attach itself to all elements with that data attribute. That's kinda how it works

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have put the whole code and more explanation on what i am trying to.